# Set environment variables in the desktop process after login

Tags: environment-variables, desktop-environment

I can set environment variables to be inherited by all processes in `~/.profile`. This works because the desktop environment (eg. gnome-shell) runs this file on login. gnome-shell then updates its own environment variables. Because each process (firefox, xterm, emacs) has gnome-shell as an ancestor, they inherit these environment variables.

Is there a way to update the environment variables in this process (gnome-shell) after login? I envision something like

```
$ xdg-set FOO=BAR
```

then in a new terminal you can immediately see

```
$ echo $FOO
BAR
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment is passed to a new process in a similar manner as the command line arguments are: they are copied into the new process' address space. They are not passed "by reference", so a change in some ancestor process' environment is not reflected in the descendant processes.

This means you can only change the environment of a process by manipulating the process itself, and only if the process offers a means to do so, e.g. setting a variable in a shell. This change in the environment is then typically reflected in any child processes the process might spawn.

Comment: Yes, I only care about new processes spawned.